# using cx_freeze in spyder

Tags: python-3.x, executable, spyder, cx-freeze

I installed cx_Freeze using pip:

```
C:\Users\Sarah\Documents\PythonScripts>python -m pip install cx_Freeze --upgrade
Collecting cx_Freeze
  Downloading cx_Freeze-5.0.2-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl (162kB)
Installing collected packages: cx-Freeze
Successfully installed cx-Freeze-5.0.2
```

However, I get this error when I try to execute a script:

```
setup.py build
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Sarah\Documents\PythonScripts\setup.py", line 9, in <module>
    from cx_freeze import setup, Executable
ImportError: No module named cx_freeze
```

When I check the system path, I get all this information

```
print (sys.path)
['', 'C:\\Users\\Sarah\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\spyder\\utils\\site', 'C:\\Users\\Sarah\\Documents\\PythonScripts', 'C:\\Users\\Sarah\\Anaconda3\\python36.zip', 'C:\\Users\\Sarah\\Anaconda3\\DLLs', 'C:\\Users\\Sarah\\Anaconda3\\lib', 'C:\\Users\\Sarah\\Anaconda3', 'C:\\Users\\Sarah\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\Users\\Sarah\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\Sphinx-1.5.6-py3.6.egg', 'C:\\Users\\Sarah\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 'C:\\Users\\Sarah\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 'C:\\Users\\Sarah\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin', 'C:\\Users\\Sarah\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\setuptools-27.2.0-py3.6.egg', 'C:\\Users\\Sarah\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\IPython\\extensions', 'C:\\Users\\Sarah\\.ipython']
```

I am assuming that somehow, the path to the cx_freeze module is lost in here somewhere. I would really appreciate some simple (novice user) ideas for how to go about fixing this.

I tried copying the folder cx-freeze to the `PythonScripts` folder but that didn't help.

Comment: What is the content of setup.py ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know why you are getting this error and I do not think it has anything to do with the file path.

Try:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
```

in the place of

```
from cx_freeze import setup, Executable
```

in your setup.py script

and this error should fix (you had f not F).

Comment: oh I feel such a fool - thank you for spotting that. I've hit other issues now, but I'll plough on. *head in hands* doh!

Comment: @Sarah Crabbe:  No worries.  I have certainly made that mistake before. Very happy to help.  Keep trying and searching, and you'll get you executable. Good Luck !

Comment: @Sarah Crabbe:  Also since my answer corrected you problem you should mark it as the correct answer so others can learn not to make that mistake as well (believe me many have (me included)).

Comment: This is a great answer. how do i mark it as correct? @Simon

Comment: @SarahCrabbe - On the left of my answer you will notice two arrows one points up the other down, those are to vote (15 reputation at least to vote) and underneath that there is the outline of a tick.  Press on the tick and it will go green.  There you have marked you answer as correct .